# Return a formatted text file with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to create a page with the last 100 rows from a text file (like a log file) within my Flask app. So I need a simple formatted text (with line numbers at least) and not like a plain text file (for example, GitHub codes).

I saw similar problems for other languages, but I'm unsure if it is best to handle it with HTML/CSS or Flask itself.
Here is my script, which returns 100 last lines as a simple plain text:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import Response


app = Flask(__name__)


def tail(file, n=1, bs=1024):
    f = open(file)
    f.seek(0,2)
    l = 1-f.read(1).count('\n')
    B = f.tell()
    while n >= l and B > 0:
            block = min(bs, B)
            B -= block
            f.seek(B, 0)
            l += f.read(block).count('\n')
    f.seek(B, 0)
    l = min(l,n)
    lines = f.readlines()[-l:]
    f.close()
    return lines

@app.route('/logs', methods = ['GET'])
def print_logs():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        file_path = "Logs.txt"
        data = tail(file_path, 100)
        return Response(data, mimetype='text/plain')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="localhost", port=80, debug=True, threaded=True)
```

Comment: If it works - what is your question? If not - what is the error you're facing?

Comment: @Jan I need a formatted text, not a plain text file. Something like GitHub does with codes.

Comment: Github uses Javascript+CSS to format code... It doesn't return a text/plain response

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes indeed, I need something like that to display my log.

Comment: are you talking about syntax highlighting?

Comment: @MarcWagner It would be good but my need is showing line numbers.

Comment: Start with returning an HTML file and take your pick at Javascript libraries, for example https://prismjs.com/plugins/line-numbers/

Comment: Please show is some sample input and output.